# How can I run Wraith and Bash commands from my electron app?

Tags: javascript, bash, electron

I'v trimmed my code to make it easier to read, I hope you can help.

I am building a visual regression testing application through electron. Ideally user can run wraith test from a GUI.

I am close to setting it up and I just need the application to be able to run wraith and bash commands through Electron.

I've tried using
`const exec = require("child_process").exec`
with no success, maybe theres something I'm missing.

My `test.sh` file is

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World again"
cd ..
wraith capture config.yaml
```

i've tried:

`exec('node ./test.sh');`

and

```
var myscript = exec('bash ./test.sh');
myscript.stdout.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
myscript.stderr.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

These console.log/echo the `Hello World` msg but none of the remaining commands seem to run.

Is there a method to run a bash script from Electron the same way you would run `bash ./test.sh` from your command line?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Moe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to run a bash script from my electron app.

I utilised [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to execute shell scripts in the command line environment.

```
const {execSync} = require('child_process')

execSync('bash ./test.sh', {stdio: 'inherit', cwd: '/Users/user_name/utils/visual-regression-testing/src/bash'})
```

Worked a treat with `cwd` being the folder to execute the command from.

Hope it helps anyone else with the same issue.